# How To fetch all rows of a table from SQL database using SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a `Grid View` in which there is a `Date` column. In database I have one unique id column and a Date column. I want to get all the ids from the SQL query so that I can get all the ids for a particular date.
For example if I write "27-06-2013" then all ids 121,123,124 receive. When I am doing using `Response.Write` I am getting only a single id.
and all the ids then I want to show in grid view.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Scheduleappointment where Doctor_Id=@docid and Convert(varchar(5),Start_Time,108)+'-'+Convert(varchar(5),End_Time,108)=@time and Date=@date", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docid", Label1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", timing.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
conopen();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    Response.Write(dr["Id"].ToString());
}
```

I want to show these id values in single row of grid view.Like 121,123 in single row next  to date 27-06-2013.

Comment: show us the code what u r doing?

Comment: select id from tablename where date='27-06-2013 '

Comment: @subhash-bt its not giving all the ids for 27-06-2013.I have tried this.

Comment: i m not getting that tolist();..when i m writing list<string> ids=new list<string>();

Comment: ohh sorry my bad, instead of **if** use **While(dr.Read()) { Response.Write(dr["Id"].ToString()); }**

Comment: Post it as an answer Mr Sharma, nearly stole your thunder there. :D

Comment: Sorry, didn't click `add/show more comments` until I posted the answer.

Comment: Can the values or id can be shown in gridview in single row

Comment: i want to show the values in gridview also

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with the last part

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    Response.Write(dr["Id"].ToString());
}
```

The if will evaluate and read only once.  If there is at least one row, it will be written.  You probably need while, to read until there are no more rows.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    Response.Write(dr["Id"].ToString());
}
```

You will probably also want to add some formatting (spaces or line breaks between values) as well as clean up code (close the data reader, etc.) after writing.